# Prevent duplicates in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm learning Node / Mongoose, and trying to figure out how to prevent duplicates in an array of ListItems:

```
var listitemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   rank: Number
});
```

...which exist inside a user:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    list: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "ListItem"
    }]  
});
```

...based on whether the user already has the name within his/her list. I was looking into `$addtoset` but can't really figure out how to put conditions when dealing with an object. The [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.addToSet) weren't very helpful and I can't seem to find similar examples online.
Right now my 'POST' request is a mess and looks like this:

```
router.post("/editlist", isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    User.findById(req.user._id).populate("list").exec(function(err , user) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/editlist");
        } else {
            //prevent duplicates based on username
            User.update(
                { "_id": req.user._id },
                { $addToSet: { "streamName": req.body.listitem.name}
            });
            res.redirect("/watch");
         }
    });
});
```

Can anyone send me on my way? My `$addToSet` isn't pushing items onto the `list` array.

Comment: Why are you pushing to the `streamName` field instead of `list`?

Comment: yeah that was my bad, getting another error now though

Answer (score 0):

According to the [$addToSet documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/), the operator is used in this form:

> { $addToSet: { field1: value1, ... } }

where `field` is an Array.

To add an item to the `list` array, we do:

```
User.update({
  { "_id": req.user._id },
  { $addToSet: { list: {"streamName": req.body.listitem.name } }}
});
```

You'll need to update the `userSchema` definition:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    list: [listitemSchema]  
});
```

Comment: hmm I changed it but now I'm getting "Cast to undefined failed for value "[object Object]" at path "list""

Comment: It was a problem with the schema definition. I've updated the answer.